# ChannelData is returning null

Tags: c#, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have created a web app bot using botframework v4 and have integrated the same with a web application using an Iframe.
I want to access the current url of the page the bot is in.

I have tried back channel mechanism but failed to get any value from the server side inside ChannelData.
I have script tag **src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"**> within the head tag and Iframe **iframe id="chatBot" src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/EdgewellSampleBot?s=xxx'  style='min-width: 400px; width: 100%; min-height: 500px;'>**
within the body tag and calling the **getUrl()** on load of the page.

```
<script>
    function getURL()
    {
var dl = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    secret: 'xxx',           
    webSocket: false,
    pollingInterval: 1000,
});

var urlref = window.location.href;

BotChat.App({
    botConnection: {
        ...dl,
        postActivity: activity => dl.postActivity({
            ...activity,
            channelData: { pageurl: urlref }
        })
    },
    user: { id: 'userid' },
    bot: { id: 'xxx' },
    resize: 'detect'
}, document.getElementById("chatBot"));
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are using WebChat v3. Could you upgrade to webChat v4 and try using [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.a.backchannel-piggyback-on-outgoing-activities) sample which uses the channelData property?

Comment: Thank you, i actually did get the solution to my question.